# What is Nano Boost's targeting sensitivity?

Tags: overwatch

[Last update on PTR](https://playoverwatch.com/en-us/blog/20529203) added "Allows players to adjust Nano Boost’s targeting sensitivity". But what exactly Nano Boost’s targeting sensitivity is? I thought it is how exactly you need to aim at a target to use nano boost on it, but tried two extreme values of 100 and 10 and didn't notice any difference.

Comment: @dly It's a button press there's no mouse movement when ult-ing as Ana

Comment: This feature was put in place after a number of players accidentally used their nano boost on champions like Lucio or Mercy when they actually wanted to hit Reinhardt or Roadhog. It's sometimes hard to hit a specific hero when everyone is clustered up - this change makes it a little easier to pick the right target in a crowd. I believe it's also used for skills such as Mercy's targeted dash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm getting information from [this video.](https://youtu.be/UCerRIrjYew?t=3m48s)

Essentially, this sensitivity slider changes how accurate you need to be when attempting to use abilities on Friendly and Enemy heroes. When at a higher sensitivity, a player must be more accurate when targeting enemies and friendlies. At lower sensitivities, the targeting is a bit more forgiving.

In relation to Ana, this is to prevent the relatively common issue of Nano-boosting heroes unintentionally, and has even spawned a new meme of "BOOSTIOOOOOOO" when accidentally Nano-Boosting a Lucio, who happens to be a very mobile hero. Now, with a higher sensitivity, the user may need some more practice in aiming where they mean, but they have a much greater chance of actually boosting who they mean to.

Answer (score 0):

It's not exactly explained, nor any website publishing the PTR update as a 'News item' has went into any effort to explain what the "targeting sensitivity" means.

But given it's mostly if not all, on auto-locking spells it's pretty safe to assume that the slider would adjust how quick the auto-locking feature is to jump between players when looking around.

For Ana's case you'd have a bit more time to press Q when looking at Reinhardt and you won't get a Boostio as soon as he casually slides in the vicinity of your line of sight.

Basically you get some room for error when he moves and you try to target him.

Some source-ish battle.net forum [post](https://us.battle.net/forums/en/overwatch/topic/20753356155#post-9).

Comment: Relevant: https://youtu.be/UCerRIrjYew?t=3m48s

Comment: @Kaizerwolf, so this is not about time, but about accuracy. This should be an answer.

Answer (score 0):

So the way it works, after 5 minutes of testing, is that the LOWER your sensitivity for the nano is, the more center you need to be to your targets mid mass to land the nano on them. Basically, if you are tired of hitting thick ole mercy right next to you instead of genji blading off in the distance, turn the sens down, to get a more accurate target acquisition. This is the same case for the mercy beam sensitivity, the lower it is the less you fight with getting the beam on the right guy.